# how to log if the user has the app, before showing the branch banner

Tags: branch.io

I would like to log whether or not the user has the app, then programmatically show the banner on our own terms. Is this possible? To programmatically show the banner I mean. Right now I'm setting `no_journeys` to true in the `init` method. https://github.com/BranchMetrics/web-branch-deep-linking-attribution#initbranch_key-options-callback

In our current setup the SDK only loads if the user is eligible to see the banner (there are no extra filters in the Branch journey banner).

Answer (score 0):

Passing `no_journeys` as `true` will make sure that the users DO NOT see the journey even if they are eligible for the journey.

Regarding your question of checking if the user already has the app or no, in the init function’s callback you get a field by the name `has_app` of type boolean.

Alternatively you can also set up audience filters from the dashboard to target the users at a more granular level. You can find more details about it [here](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/journeys-app-banners#section-advanced-audience-filters)